# Software way to keep a special key pressed (Sticky-keys replacement for mouse actions)?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I am one-handed. In Windows-10 often I need to keep a special key (Ctrl, Alt or Sjift) pressed while pressing another key or mouse clicking/ dragging  I tried the Sticky Keys feature, but it does not work for me in some situations (e,g. to emulate Alt-PrintScreen or with mouse actions). As a workaround I put a heavy object to the physical keyboard. but it is difficult to prevent it from falling or touching the nearby keys.
Is there a software way to do the same, other than with the physical keyboard (maybe with the on-screen keyboard?) I am OK with AHK programming or Perl / python or any other programming solution. In other words, I am looking for a Sticky-Keys replacement that would work for mouse actions and for special actions such as Print Screen.